# Parsing specific information from html source file with BeautifulSoup and saving it to a .csv file

Tags: python, parsing, csv, html-parsing, lxml

What I'm trying to do is extract/parse the order information from the HTML source file and save it in a .csv file.

What I need from the html source is all the: 
 1. order numbers (example: 99), 
 2. the names (example: Peter Haans) and 
 3. the order amounts (example: € 41,94).

Because I'm new to Python (and programming in general) I'm having a hard time parsing the information correctly and saving it.

Currently I'm using this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)

orderField = soup.tbody.tr.next_sibling.next_sibling
orderNumber = soup.tbody.tr.next_sibling.next_sibling.contents[3]
customerName = soup.tbody.tr.next_sibling.next_sibling.contents[5]
totalAmount = soup.tbody.tr.next_sibling.next_sibling.contents[9]

print orderField
print orderNumber
print customerName
print totalAmount
```

You can view the full html code [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jkmtzb11mrtijdh/bestellingen.html) (Dropbox link).

This is a part of the HTML code I'm working with:

```
<tbody>
<tr class="filter">
<td></td>
<td align="right"><input type="text" name="filter_order_id" value="" size="4" style="text-align: right;"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="filter_customer" value="" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true"></td>
<td><select name="filter_order_status_id">
<option value="*"></option>
<option value="0">Afgebroken bestellingen</option>
<option value="23">Bestelling geannuleerd</option>
<option value="17">Bestelling ontvangen</option>
<option value="24">Bestelling verzonden</option>
<option value="22">Betaling mislukt</option>
<option value="20">Betaling ontvangen via Bank</option>
<option value="19">Betaling ontvangen via PayPal</option>
<option value="21">Betaling via Bank mislukt</option>
<option value="18">Betaling via PayPal mislukt</option>
<option value="25">Gereed voor afhalen (Delft)</option>
<option value="26">Wachten op betaling</option>
</select></td>
<td align="right"><input type="text" name="filter_total" value="" size="4" style="text-align: right;"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="filter_date_added" value="" size="12" class="date hasDatepicker" id="dp1372950239097"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="filter_date_modified" value="" size="12" class="date hasDatepicker" id="dp1372950239098"></td>
<td align="right"><a onclick="filter();" class="button">Filter</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;"> <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="99">
</td>
<td class="right">99</td>
<td class="left">Peter Haans</td>
<td class="left">Betaling ontvangen via Bank</td>
<td class="right">€ 41,94</td>
<td class="left">03-07-2013</td>
<td class="left">03-07-2013</td>
<td class="right"> [ <a href="http://www.fonexshop.nl/admin/index.php?route=sale/order/info&amp;token=470a3c2fa62a4cc029825bd6010520bb&amp;order_id=99">Bekijk</a> ]
[ <a href="http://www.fonexshop.nl/admin/index.php?route=sale/order/update&amp;token=470a3c2fa62a4cc029825bd6010520bb&amp;order_id=99">Wijzigen</a> ]
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;"> <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="98">
</td>
<td class="right">98</td>
<td class="left">Peter Haans</td>
<td class="left">Bestelling geannuleerd</td>
<td class="right">€ 41,94</td>
<td class="left">03-07-2013</td>
<td class="left">03-07-2013</td>
<td class="right"> [ <a href="http://www.fonexshop.nl/admin/index.php?route=sale/order/info&amp;token=470a3c2fa62a4cc029825bd6010520bb&amp;order_id=98">Bekijk</a> ]
[ <a href="http://www.fonexshop.nl/admin/index.php?route=sale/order/update&amp;token=470a3c2fa62a4cc029825bd6010520bb&amp;order_id=98">Wijzigen</a> ]
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;"> <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="96">
</td>
<td class="right">96</td>
<td class="left">Akam Rezakhani</td>
<td class="left">Bestelling verzonden</td>
<td class="right">€ 41,94</td>
<td class="left">01-07-2013</td>
<td class="left">02-07-2013</td>
<td class="right"> [ <a href="http://www.fonexshop.nl/admin/index.php?route=sale/order/info&amp;token=470a3c2fa62a4cc029825bd6010520bb&amp;order_id=96">Bekijk</a> ]
[ <a href="http://www.fonexshop.nl/admin/index.php?route=sale/order/update&amp;token=470a3c2fa62a4cc029825bd6010520bb&amp;order_id=96">Wijzigen</a> ]
</td>
</tr>
```

Any ideas on how to get this working correctly?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Someone provided a very good answer to help me solve it by modifying the template that generates the html page.

He suggested adding additional class names like orderId, customerName and orderAmount.

But for some reason he deleted his answer. I want to thank him because it got me one step closer.

I get three raw lists (with html code) of all the order id's, customer name's and order amounts.

This is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml

html_doc = open('bestellingen.html', 'r')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc,'lxml')

orderId = soup.select('.orderId')
customerName = soup.select('.customerName')
orderAmount = soup.select('.orderAmount')

print orderId
print customerName
print orderAmount
```

Is there a way to filter up the raw html so it only shows the information I need?

Comment: First you say you're having a hard time getting it to work, then you say you're looking for recommendations of how to optimise it: which is it?

Comment: My apologies. I need help getting it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone provided a very good answer to help me solve it by modifying the template that generates the html page.

He suggested adding additional class names like orderId, customerName and orderAmount.

I want to thank him because it got me one step closer.

I get three raw lists (with html code) of all the order id's, customer name's and order amounts.

This is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml

html_doc = open('bestellingen.html', 'r')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc,'lxml')

orderId = soup.select('.orderId')
customerName = soup.select('.customerName')
orderAmount = soup.select('.orderAmount')

print orderId
print customerName
print orderAmount
```

Is there a way to filter up the raw html so it only shows the information I need?